# ASP.NET: Serve static files from specific directory

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

I'm running an ASP.NET app which is a back-end (provides REST services) for Single Page Application.
The SPA lives in a directory one level up than my REST app. 
Here's what the structure looks like:

`- Solution Directory
  + RestApp [ASP.NET project]
  - SPAClient [plain html + js]
      * index.html
      * script.js`

How do I configure my web.config / IIS & IISExpress to serve files from `SPAClient` unless the url is prefixed with "api" (in which case I want to route the request to an app)?

What I want is to route the following request
`/api/foo` to my RestApp 
yet any other requests (not prefixed with `/api/`) to the SPAClient?

I want the real solution, not something like "copy contents of SPAClient to your ASP.NET directory)

Comment: Both IIS and IIS Express supports URL rewriting. That simply resolves your issue if you redirect the requests to actual static files.